# Trying to achieve two mixed transitions at the same time

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

This is my code:

```
 import SwiftUI
 @main
struct BouncingApp: App {
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        BounceAble()
    }
}
}
struct BounceAble: View {
@State var bounce: Bool = false
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        Button("Bounce") {
            withAnimation(.easeOut) {
                bounce.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
    .overlay {
        if bounce {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .transition(.slide)
                .transition(.scale)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation(.easeIn) {
                        bounce.toggle()
                    }
                }
        }
    }
   }
   }
```

The problem is i want my Circle to slide while growing at the same time. I thought adding two transitions at a time would does the job but it did not. is there any logical problem with my code? thank you so much.

Comment: Actually the description of desired effect is not very clear... it can be interpreted in many ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you wanted something like this one

```
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .transition(.slide.combined(with: .scale))
```

or this one

```
    Circle()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .transition(.scale.combined(with: .slide))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add two `transition` to your view, it would always occur the first one.

You can combine two transitions together to achieve your goal design:

```
.transition(.scale.combined(with: .slide))
```

Note that if you use `.slide` before `.scale`, you would not get the same result.

You should test out both options and see which one fits your desired design most.